# Using WiringPi C library through SSH on Netbeans

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

How can I use WiringPi library through SSH on Netbeans? When I run a simple HelloWorld program, it works.

This is the output message:

```
Copying project files to /root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64 at root@RASPBERRYPI
Building project files list...
Checking directory structure...
Checking previously uploaded files...
Checking links...
Uploading changed files:
    Zipping 10 changed files...
    Uploading zip to root@RASPBERRYPI...
    Unzipping changed files...
Checking exec permissions...
Uploading changed files finished successfully.

cd '/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/blinkingled
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -std=c11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux
gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/blinkingled build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o: In function `main':
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:24: undefined reference to `wiringPiSetup'
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:29: undefined reference to `pinMode'
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:32: undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:34: undefined reference to `delay'
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:35: undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED/main.c:37: undefined reference to `delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/blinkingled' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/blinkingled] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/.netbeans/remote/RASPBERRYPI/win-7pjgqkgjsj4-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Public/Remote Projects/BlinkingLED'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite old post, but since I've had the same problem and I've resolved it I'm now writing down the solution, so if someone needs it, it's ready ;)

The only thing to do is to add some parameters to the compilation command, in particular the path to binaries and includes plus the -lwiringpi option.

To do that in NetBeans, rightclick on the project, then properties. From there, Build->C Compiler.

Now, find the voice Additional Options, open it and copy paste the following:

-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lwiringPi

(that are the paths to the standard installation of wiringPi, if you have changed the location of the library change the paths accordingly)

Now it should work, at least it worked for me.

Hope it helped someone,
Bye

EDIT:

I forgot to add that you must ssh as root user, otherwise wiringPi doesn't work.

For that you must do:

passwd root

to set root password

sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

And change PermitRootLogin to yes

reboot